# Send_keys in selenium doesn't activate the submit button but manual entering does

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm struggling with a phone number field that I fill using send_keys function in selenium. Actually, the submit button is supposed to be enabled after filling out the phone number, but it doesn't except if I enter the phone number manually.

I tried to click on the phone number field before filling it out, but it still doesn't work. Here is the code I'm using:

```
phone=webdriver.find_element_by_id("phonenumber")
phone.click()
phone.clear()
phone.send_keys(number)
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: please add the website information screenshots etc

Comment: What does "number" equal to in your above example? Seem like you're using a variable here but don't show it declared. That's probably why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution by using actions and Keys.NUMPAD. Here is a sample of code:

```
phone=webdriver.find_element_by_id("phonenumber")
actions=ActionChains(webdriver)
actions.click(phone)
actions.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD0)
actions.send_keys(Keys.NUMPAD2)
actions.perform()
```

This way i can submit the phone number like if i entered it manually!

Comment: could you add the website information

Answer (score 1):

You can enter mobile number as following:

```
phone=webdriver.find_element_by_id("phonenumber")
phone.click()
phone.clear()
phone.send_keys("0123456")
```